# mod_rewrite, 301 problem

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, 301-redirect

Currently I can access specific site in two ways:

```
 1. http://a.com/foo/bar
 2. http://a.com/index.php?url=foo/bar
```

What I'm trying to achive is to allow to do it only using first way, and make redirect 301 on the second to the first one. Here's the code which I made so far and put into .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>  
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]

  #tricky part
  RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php\?url=?(.*)\ HTTP/
  RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://a.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Currently it do *almost* all the job, it's redirecting index.php to /, but index.php?url=foo/bar to /?url=foo/bar and I can't manage to make it right. TIA.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Everything You Ever Wanted to Know about Mod_Rewrite Rules but Were Afraid to Ask?](http://serverfault.com/questions/214512/everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know-about-mod-rewrite-rules-but-were-afraid-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
RewriteCond %{query_string} ^url=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^.*index.php$ /$1? [R=301]
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly it doesn't work. It redirects me back to main domain (a.com).